# Galois group of an octic over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: galois-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $L=K(\beta)$ where $\beta$ is a root of $f(x)=27x^8+72x^4-16$. This problem comes from Silverman and Tate; $\beta$ is the $y$-coordinate of one of the 3-torsion points of $y^2=x^3+x$. Let
\begin{equation*}
\beta = \sqrt[4]{\frac{8\sqrt{3}-12}{9}},
\end{equation*}
and if we set
\begin{equation*}
\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt{3}-3}{3}} = \frac{\beta^2\sqrt{3}}{2},\quad
\alpha' = -\frac{i}{\alpha\sqrt{3}},\quad \beta' = \sqrt[4]{\frac{-8\sqrt{3}-12}{9}},
\end{equation*}
then the roots of $f(x)$ are $\pm\beta, \pm i\beta, \pm\beta', \pm i\beta'$, and the 3-torsion points of $y^2=x^3+x$ are (together with the point at infinity)
\begin{equation*}
(\alpha, \pm\beta),\ (-\alpha, \pm i\beta),\ (\alpha', \pm \beta'),\ (-\alpha', \pm i\beta').
\end{equation*}
I am trying to understand the Galois group of $L/K$ ($L$ is Galois over $K$). My first attempt was to show that the group is cyclic, with generator $\beta\mapsto \beta'$. However, $\beta\mapsto\beta'$ also maps $\alpha$ to $-\alpha'$, and $(-\alpha',\beta')$ is not a 3-torsion point of the curve. Thus this cannot be an automorphism of $L/K$, although I cannot see why it isn't. (Of note is that Sage seems to think that this is an automorphism of $L/K$.) The map $\beta\mapsto i\beta$ preserves the 3-torsion points, but has only order four.

So: 1) what is going on with $\beta\mapsto\beta'$? Is it an $L/K$-automorphism? If so, I must have done something wrong with my calculation of the image of $\alpha$ under that automorphism. And 2) if it is not, what is a second generator of the Galois group other than $\beta\mapsto i\beta$?

I'd appreciate not getting back a complete solution, as I'm really trying to understand this group in preparation for doing another exercise.

Comment: $[L:K] = 8$ and $Gal(L/K(\sqrt3))$ is generated by $\beta\to i\beta$, so the image of $\alpha= \frac{\beta^2\sqrt{3}}{2}$ under $\beta\to \beta'$  is $ \frac{-\beta'^2\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Why do you say it is $= -\frac{i}{\alpha\sqrt{3}}$ ?

Comment: @reuns Because those two are equal!

Comment: I just checked in magma, it is cyclic generated by $\beta\to 1/16*(-9*i - 9)*\beta^5 + 1/4*(-5*i - 5)*\beta$ which sends $\alpha$ to $= -\frac{i}{\alpha\sqrt{3}}$ and those are roots of $y^2=x^3+x$. That it agrees or not with your post depends on the branch you chose for $\beta' = \sqrt[4]{\frac{-8\sqrt{3}-12}{9}}$.

Comment: $f(x)$ is irreducible modulo five, so the Galois group of its splitting field **OVER $\Bbb{Q}$** has an automorphism that permutes the roots in an 8-cycle (= the Frobenius element related to $p=5$). I don't know yet, whether there is such an element that fixes the intermediate field $\Bbb{Q}(i)$. You would think that raising to the fifth power fixes $i$, wouldn't you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\beta$ is real and positive, and $\beta'$ has argument $\pi/4$, then I don't see the problem. If $\sigma$ is an automorphism with the property $\sigma(\beta)=\beta'$ then:

- $\sigma(\beta^4)=\beta'^4$ implying that $\sigma(\sqrt3)=-\sqrt3$, and hence
- $\sigma(\alpha)=-\sqrt3\beta'^2/2$, a complex number with argument $-\pi/2$, agreeing with the argument of $\alpha'$.

This suggests to me that $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha'$, just as you would expect from the list of 3-torsion points. I think this settles your first question, and seems to make the second question moot, but the structure of the relevant Galois groups is not clear to me yet.

Comment: I turned this to CW when I realized that the content is equivalent to that of reuns's 1st comment.

Comment: My guess is that the Galois group over $\Bbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to a semidirect product $C_8\rtimes C_2$. If the generators of the two factors are $a$ and $b$ respectively, we have the extra relation $bab^{-1}=a^3$.

Comment: I see my error. I had forgotten to account for the action of $\sigma$ on $\sqrt{3}$. Thanks.